# GoTo Declaration in IntelliJ goes to absolute instead of relative path

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an Angular 6 project in IntelliJ. When I try to go to a class or method declaration (Ctrl + B) it takes me to the correct file, but using an absolute path to it. When I open a file through the project explorer (on IntelliJ) it uses a relative path. As a consequence, a file that is openened with an absolute path cannot be found with the "target" icon in the project explorer. This makes moving from one source file to another very slow, and I end up looking for the file on the project explorer every time.

My project files path looks like:

/workspace/MyProject/src/app/

When I open a file (file1.ts for this example) on IntelliJ from the project explorer, it shows a relative path as:

MyProject/src/app/file1.ts

Inside "file1.ts" I have a reference to a class inside "file2.ts", which is on the same path as "file1.ts", But when I try to jump to "file2.ts" using "Go to declaration", it will open "file2.ts" using an absolute path, like:

/workspace/MyProject/src/app/file2.ts

The consequence of this is that if I click on button "Scroll from Source" on the project explorer, it will not take me to the file (as it expects it to have a relative path, apparently). I know that both absolute and relative paths are exactly the same, but IntelliJ will not find it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "goto declaration uses the absolute path." Do you mean it's taking you to a file outside the project's directory structure?
`Ctrl+B` should take you to that file within your project's source, not to it in the target dir, nor to it outside the project structure (unless it is from a dependency). If that is not happening, there is definitely something wrong with your configuration. But more detail would be needed to know what exactly is wrong. Add some screenshots of the project structure window.

Comment: Hi @Javaru, I added more details. Thanks!

Comment: "Scroll **from** Source", which you said you have selected, is used to highlight a file in the project window when you open or switch to it in the editor. If you want it so that upon selecting a file in the project tool window it automatically opens in the editor, you need to enable "Scroll **to** source". That said, it should still open if you double click on it. If not, then there is something wrong with your project configuration. I'm still not sure where in the UI you are seeing the relative vs absolute path information. I'd need to see a screenshot of where it is you are seeing that.